# Select2 keep input original format

Tags: jquery-select2

Using select2 is really cool but I would simply like my input to stay a simple, basic search box, without the fancy styling and formatting from select2. I couldn't find a way to achieve this yet.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Bootstrap Typeahead

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

```
//JS
var subjects = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON']; 
$('#search').typeahead({source: subjects})

//HTML
<div class="well">
 <input type="text" class="span3" id="search" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" data-items="4" />
</div>
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6XG8F/

Comment: This is not an answer for user's problem. Change framework. I need to use select2 and don't want to include Bootstrap just to change select2 aspect

Comment: I agree. It is not the exact answer he's looking for. It's more an alternative solution. From my experience, I did it and I have the same look everywhere. Anyway, the only solution I know and my best answer  is to use a framework: jQueryUI, bootstrap or other.